# Is there a CLI for the Watson IBM IoT service on Bluemix?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

I use the IBM Watson IoT service in Bluemix, and I would like to know if there is a CLI for this service.
For example, I want to create many types of terminals and add devices quickly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically register devices using bulk/devices operations.  https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#!/Bulk_Operations/post_bulk_devices_add

Also, this [recipe](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/multiple-iot-device-simulation-using-java-client-library/) describes how to register multiple IoT devices.

Here are some other links that may be helpful.
This recipe talks in detail about how to register a device in Watson IoT Platform - https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-register-devices-in-ibm-iot-foundation/

This Java sample shows how one can do bulk addition/deletion - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-platform-apiv2-samples/blob/master/java/api-samples-v2/README.md

Comment: @Arthur, you thank people by clicking the green checkmark next to their answer.